# Созданную в MemoryStream картинку сохранить word документ используя openxml

Tags: c#, openxml

Создаю картинку qr code в memorystream сохраняю ее на жесткий диск и потом могу вставить ее в word документ. Можно минуя сохранения ее на жестком диске сохранить ее в документе?
Код создания qr-code

```
 var bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new System.DrawingCore.Rectangle(0, 0, pixelData.Width, pixelData.Height),
            System.DrawingCore.Imaging.ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, System.DrawingCore.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
            try
            {
                // we assume that the row stride of the bitmap is aligned to 4 byte multiplied by the width of the image
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(pixelData.Pixels, 0, bitmapData.Scan0,
                pixelData.Pixels.Length);
            }
            finally
            {
                bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
            }
            // save to stream as PNG
            bitmap.Save(@"c:\ggg.png", System.DrawingCore.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

Так загружаю в документ:

```
  using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"c:\ggg.png", FileMode.Open))
                    //using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(memoryStreamBitmap, FileMode.Open))
                    {
                        image.FeedData(stream);
                    }

                   // image.FeedData(memoryStreamBitmap);                       

                    AddImageToBody(wordDocument, mainPart.GetIdOfPart(image));
```

[Документация по ставке брал с msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb497430.aspx)

Comment: Bitmap сохраняете в `MemoryStream`, далее его передаете в `FeedData`.

Comment: можно пример кода?, File.Open надо передовать строку пути к файлу, а он и так в памяти какой у него путь не понятно

Comment: Не надо `File.Open`! Не надо создавать файл! Вместо `FileStream` создавайте `MemoryStream`, в него пишите битмап.

Comment: Создал memorystream пишу этот  поток в документ, а выскакивает  ошибка изображение не найдено

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос, добавив в него код. Вангую, что нужно `memoryStream.Position = 0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, действительно надо было сохранить memorystream и передать поток в метод где будет сохраняться документ и указать `msBitmap.Position = 0;`
`var msBitmap = new MemoryStream();

   bitmap.Save(msBitmap, System.DrawingCore.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
   return msBitmap;`
И сохранение документа 
`msBitmap.Position = 0;
   image.FeedData(msBitmap);`